# I need better understanding on for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop

can someone explain me how this **for loop** works (**Line 9 in code below**), and also if you can show me a simple example with it can be very helpfull, thank you anyways!

```
1 #include <iostream>
2 #include <cstdlib>
3 
4 using namespace std;

5 int main(){
6     int n, a , b , ma=0,mb=1000000001;
7     cin >> n ;
8     cin >> a;
9     for( n--; n ; --n ){
10         cin >> b;
11         if(abs(a-b) < abs(ma-mb))
12             ma=a , mb=b;
13         else
14             if(abs(a-b) == abs(ma-mb) && ma+mb > a+b)
15                 ma=a , mb=b;
16         a = b;
17     }
18     cout << ma << " " << mb;
19     return 0;
20 }
```

Comment: It's best to understand that fundamental concepts of the language from a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The best way to understand such a loop is to use the debugger of your IDE and step through the code line by line so see what happens to the variables and what path is taken.

Comment: Btw, this is a really bad code style, because the variables don't have any meaningful name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code smells a lot. If you give to `n` the value 10,it gives

9 (first time into loop, exectues `n--`)
every other iteration it executes `--n` till when n!=0 (which is the condition `n`

Comment: n = 10; for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) <-- i used this to solve the problem but my teacher told be is better to use this one for( n--; n ; --n ) but he didnt explain how it works, thank you very much

Comment: @Gabriel: I have no idea why your teacher would say such a thing. You should probably ask again, because that makes no sense.  I'd suggest exactly what you did

Comment: @Gabriel  The loop written as in your question is a clear example of bad code and bad practice. Clean code is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is simply another way to write a while loop.  So this:

```
for( n--; n ; --n ){
    ...
}
```

is the same as this:

```
n--;
while(n) {
    ...
    --n;
}
```

Which, in this specific case, is easier to read. First it decrements `n`, then does the loop, decrementing `n` again at the end of each loop, until that decrement causes `n` to evaluate to `false` by becoming `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop works the following way:

It runs for a certain number of times. We signify this with a condition. It has a start and an increment:

```
for (start ; condition ; increment )
{
// loop body
}
```

For loops and all loops are very useful when you want to perform repetitive tasks.

Lets say that you want to make a game and this game will have 3 rounds. Each one of those rounds can be implemented as an iteration of a for loop. It will look like this:

```
for(int round = 0; round < 3; ++round) {
// game round logic
}
```

In the above loop we start at 0. Once we reach 3, we would have already executed the for-loop 3 times. After each iteration of the for loop ++round gets executed, this increments the variable round by 1. We can increment it by a different value by doing: round+=2 or round*=2 etc.